# 1D binpacking: pack vector of sorted doubles into a fixed number of bins so that they are equally filled

Tags: algorithm, packing, bin-packing

I have a sorted vector of n floats/doubles. I want to pack them into k bins, each with the same maximum size. The goal is to pack them in a way so that the space left in each bin is maximized.

My naive algorithm packed the lengths into the bin that still has the most space left. The problem I encoutered was a case where this algorithm failed where an even simpler algorithm succeeded. That simpler algorithm was the standard example of packing the numbers in the first bin they fit into - and open a new one when they don't.

Since my problem a very easy special case of the general problem (it's 1D, has sorted inputs, fixed number of bins, each bin the same size) I was hoping for a better way to solve it. Ideally exact, but better than mine would still be helpful.

Also the condition that the space left should be maximized may be ignored it if leads to an easier/better solution.

edit: An example would be an input sequence of 5.0, 4.0 and 3.0 with a max bin size of 9.0. A naive solution would be 5.0 and 4.0 in the first bin, 3.0 in the second. But I want 5.0 and 3.0 to be in one, and 4.0 in the other bin so that the space that is left in the bins is as big as possible.

To clarify on the space: The total space left in all the bins is always the same, independent of where each length is put in. But I want that the space left in each bin is "as equal as possible". I understand that that is a secondary condition next to the optimal bin packing. Therefore if it helps, that condition can be ignored. I'm not sure yet myself how much it increases the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: It is not clear, but I assume that a double value from the vector takes space equally to its value in a bin, correct? Can you also specify what you mean by maximizing the space left in each bin? I think a simple example of what you want to achieve might help here.

Comment: Alright, I added some clarification and an example.

Comment: The wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem states "The decision problem (deciding if objects will fit into a specified number of bins) is NP-complete." This holds even for the simple 1D case.

Comment: For the naive algorithm you proposed, did you start with the largest values first? Another approach would be to adapt it, using a best-fit strategy from the wiki page.